# Error while sending data from lambda to firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am testing my code that sends data from aws lambda to firehose. This is my code:

```
client = boto3.client('firehose')
for item in items:
    response = client.put_record(
        DeliveryStreamName='iot-firehose',
        Record=item)
```

My item will be a dictionary like this:

```
{
        'IMEI':123,
        'Time':'time',
        'Voltage':some voltage(type int),
        'Current':some Current(type int),
    }
```

I am getting this error, I went through documentation but I can't figure out where I am doing wrong.

```
[ERROR] ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:Missing required parameter in Record: "Data"Unknown parameter in Record: "IMEI", must be one of: DataUnknown parameter in Record: "Time", must be one of: DataUnknown parameter in Record: "Voltage", must be one of: DataUnknown parameter in Record: "Current", must be one of: DataTraceback (most recent call last):  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 19, in lambda_handler    response = client.put_record(  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 648, in _make_api_call    request_dict = self._convert_to_request_dict(  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 696, in _convert_to_request_dict    request_dict = self._serializer.serialize_to_request(  File "/var/runtime/botocore/validate.py", line 297, in serialize_to_request    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out. That data "item" that I was sending was a python **dictionary** but it can needs data that is **JSON** .SO, `json.dumps(item)` solved it. There was a syntex error also, it should be `response = client.put_record(DeliveryStreamName='iot-firehose',Record={'Data':json.dumps(item)})`.